# How to join a table with itself in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table - it is like several table concatenated because [Col1] takes two different strings and [Value] takes numerical values relating to [Col1] string. There are 2 sets of columns for segments. Analysis for each segment and later combination of segments. datestamp is also available.

```
Col1   datestamp Value
ret     1/10/14
ent     1/10/14
ret     2/1/14
ent     2/1/14
```

Finished table will look like this:

```
Col1ret  Col2ent  datestamp Value-ret Value-ent
ret       ent     1/10/14
ret       ent     2/1/14
```

What would be the SQL script to do this?

Comment: for any particular date, are there only two ret and ent entries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a simple `JOIN`:

```
select t1.Col1 as Col1ret, t2.Col1 as Col2ent, t1.datestamp, t1.value as value-ret, t2.value as value-ent
from tablename t1
  join tablename t2 on t1.datestamp = t2.datestamp
where t1.Col1 = 'ret'
  and t2.Col1 = 'ent'
```

Since it's MySQL perhaps you need to replace " with back-ticks?

Comment: I am sorry - I updated my question. The Value column is also needs to be divided as illustrated.

Comment: Suppose if I have 3 additional columns col5, col6 and colD - and colD is also a form of time value as with datestamp, how would your script change?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PIVOT TABLE to convert your query result like this

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (col1 nvarchar(5),datestamp DATETIME ,value int)

INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES ('ret',CAST('2014-10-01' AS DATE),null)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES ('ent',CAST('2014-10-01' AS DATE),null)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES ('ret',CAST('2014-2-1' AS DATE),null)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES ('ent',CAST('2014-2-1' AS DATE),null)

SELECT pv.ret
    ,pv.ent
    ,pv.datestamp
    ,pv.value
FROM (
    SELECT t.col1
        ,t.datestamp
        ,t.value
    FROM #tmp t
) as a
PIVOT (
    MAX(col1)
    FOR [col1] IN ([ret],[ent])
) as pv

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

And you will get Query result like this

```
    ret ent datestamp               value
-------------------------------------
    ret ent 2014-02-01 00:00:00.000 NULL
    ret ent 2014-10-01 00:00:00.000 NULL
```

More information see this link below 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: doesnt apply to mysql

Comment: Oh !! I don't see your tag is MySQL I think sql server sorry.

Comment: then please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table